# Prove length relationship of median and sides in triangle using triangle inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, median, triangle-inequality

AD is the median in the triangle ∆ABC, from the corner A.

Prove that $\frac{AB+AC}{2}$$>AD>$$\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}$.

I have that

$AB+AC>BC$,

$AB+BC>AC$,

$AC+BC>AB$

as well as

$AC+AD>CD$

$AD+CD>AC$

$AC+CD>AD$

and

$AB+AD>BD$

$AD+BD>AB$

$AB+BD>AD$

and

$BC=CD+BD$

I come as far as $AB+BC+AC>2AD$ and $AD>AC-BC-BD$ and now I'm really stuck and staring myself blind, going in circles.

Super grateful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far did you get? Where are you stuck? This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3490180/edit). Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple application of the triangle inequality.

Take $A'$ so that $ABCA'$ is a parallelogram. Then $2AD=AA'< AB+BA'=AB+AC$. For the other inequality, we have $AD+DB> AB$ and $AD+DC> AC$. Adding gives $2AD> AB+AC-BC$.